# VBA Paste as Values help please

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to use the code below. What I need to do is when the new sheet is created I want the data to be pasted as values vs being just a duplicate page. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub COPY_SHEET_2_NEW_SHEET()

    Dim origSht             As Worksheet
    Dim destSht             As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo eHandle

    Set origSht = ActiveSheet

    Sheets.Add.Name = InputBox("What Would You Like to Call the New Sheet?")
    Set destSht = ActiveSheet

    origSht.Cells.Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells

Exit Sub

eHandle:

    MsgBox "You must name the new sheet"
    Set origSht = Nothing
    Set destSht = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `destSht.UsedRange.Value = destSht.UsedRange.Value` after `origSht.Cells.Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to exclude the [`copy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) method's optional parameter of `Destination` (just do `origSht.Cells.Copy`) and, as your next line, use the [`Range.PasteSpecial()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) method where you can supply the optional `paste` parameter with an [`xlPasteType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype) enum, specifically the `xlPasteValues` enum value. It will look like `destSht.Cells.Paste Paste:=xlPasteValues`

It will look like:

```
Sub COPY_SHEET_2_NEW_SHEET()

  Dim origSht             As Worksheet
  Dim destSht             As Worksheet

  On Error GoTo eHandle

  Set origSht = ActiveSheet

  Sheets.Add.Name = InputBox("What Would You Like to Call the New Sheet?")
  Set destSht = ActiveSheet

  origSht.Cells.Copy
  destSht.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  Exit Sub

eHandle:

  MsgBox "You must name the new sheet"
  Set origSht = Nothing
  Set destSht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist. While it did paste into the new sheet as values I was not thinking about losing the design of the sheet. This is me being lazy. Rather than copying a specific range and repasting as values manually, is there a way to add that as a step at the end for the new sheet? Reason being the data I am copying over to a new sheet gets changed if any data is touched due to a formula function =IF(LEN('TMMCA QUERY ENTRY'!B157)=9,"0","")&('TMMCA QUERY ENTRY'!B157). Not sure if I explained that right